# Careers 2.0 bug: can't link to answer and account on StackExchange 1.0 site

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, stack-exchange

While filling out [my profile on Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/publish/22763), I wanted to link to one of my top answers and got the following error:

[image]

The link I pasted clearly is on a StackExchange site (http://biostar.stackexchange.com) but the error states that my answer does not lead to a StackExchange answer.

I think the cause for the error is that http://biostar.stackexchange.com is still running on the old/original StackExchange 1.0 platform. (There currently is an ongoing discussion within the BioStar community [whether we should migrate](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/13915/should-biostar-be-switched-over-to-the-stackexchange-network) towards [the StackExchange 2.0 platform](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/14000/should-we-accept-the-terms-for-the-migration-to-stackexchange-2-0).)

In the same vein, while adding Stack Exchange Accounts, there is no way for me to link to my [BioStar account](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/users/68/jeroen-van-goey) while that is for my career field the most relevant account.

In my opinion, if you still allow sites to continue using the StackExchange 1.0 platform, then you should make your current products backwards compatible with that platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that you can't include BioStar on your careers profile because it's an SE 1.0 site.

Sorry, but we aren't planning on supporting this. If/When BioStar decides to become an SE 2.0 site all of its data will become available to careers via the StackExchange API and you'll be able to include answers and accounts on your profile.